# How to restrict the size of a Google chrome extension popup?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, popup, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Google Chrome extension that does some basic search based on the choices provided.

This is how it looks so far

[image]

The problem is that there is a lot of white space on the sides which does not look good, especially because this is a popup and overlays on the current page.

How can I make sure that the popup uses the minimum amount of space required?

Comment: Maybe don't set a width at all, then it will expand to the minimum required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be as simple as styling the `body` element. Do you want a fixed size, fixed width, or just less margins? For fixed size, you should use `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:hidden` along with the appropriate `width` and `height`. For fixed width, use `width` and optionally `min-height`. For any of these, you should check the margins on all the block-level elements to see if that's where your whitespace is coming from.

Comment: Have you tried using [Inspect Popup](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html#inspect-popup) to check the margins?

Answer (score 5):

as nkorth said, this is quite easy, using CSS. Let me write out the code for you:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <style type="text/css">
         body {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            overflow: hidden;
         }
     </style>
  </head>
  <body>
     text text text
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [Debugging Tutorial](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html) to inspect this popup.

Maybe set the `min-width` property to `body` element could fix it. If not, please append the html code, we can check it later.