# Responsive Chrome Extension popup

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, responsive-design, viewport

I'm developing a chrome extension and I got the design as a .psd.
I have the px value of all the layers.
The deign was made on a 1225X2019 screen, resulting in the popup, fonts, margins, spacing etc. on my smaller screen being too big.

in my css file I use the px values that I get from the design, using "Adobe Assets".

I don't understand why the "meta viewport" line doesn't make it responsive. For spacing and margins I also tried to work with Bootstrap's grid (class="col-md-1") but it didn't seem to have any effect.

here's my css and html code snippets:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  width: 738px;
  background-color: #eceff1;
}
#Hired_RSS
/*Hired RSS*/

{
  padding-left: 46px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: #455a64;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 77px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 37.5px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: 0.937px;
  text-align: left;
}
#toolbar {
  background-color: #b0bec5;
  width: 738px;
  height: 67px;
}
#Feeds {
  margin-left: 47px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  background-color: #b0bec5;
  color: #455a64;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-size: 31.25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: 0.781px;
  text-align: center;
}
#Live {
  margin-right: 27px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  color: #eceff1;
  font-size: 31.25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: 0.781px;
  text-align: center;
}
#Researched {
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-size: 31.25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: 0.781px;
  text-align: center;
}
#Settings {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-size: 31.25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: 0.781px;
  text-align: center;
}
#plus {
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 97px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" ; content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="/libraries/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Cascading Style Sheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/libraries/css/popupstyle.css">
  <title>RSS Extension's Popup</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Hired_RSS">Hired RSS
    <input id="plus" type="image" src="/libraries/clipboard/plus.png" style="float: right;">
  </div>
  <div id="toolbar">
    <span class="toolbar1" id="Feeds">Feeds</span>
    <span class="toolbar1" id="Live">Live  <kbd>10</kbd></span>
    <span class="toolbar1" id="Researched">Researched  <kbd>3</kbd></span>
    <span class="toolbar1" id="Settings">Settings</span>
    <br></br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can restrict the size of popup by a fixed size, fixed width or less margins. See the reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160568/how-to-restrict-the-size-of-a-google-chrome-extension-popup?rq=1

Comment: Thanks gui47, but my problem is not with the size of the popup window but with the responsiveness of it to different resolutions/screen sizes. I want to make the font size/margins/spacing smaller as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was asked a long time ago, but since I just googled this and was frustrated with the lack of answer, I thought I'd share the solution.

col-md-_ won't work in the vast majority of cases, because the "md" class only applies on screens of a certain size, which a popup almost certainly isn't. Try col-xs-_ instead.

For more specific information on sizes, see the media queries section of bootstrap css: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries